# Workaround for Removing Liquidity

Tags: solidity, uniswap, liquidity-provider

I deployed an ERC20 contract, accidentally added liquidity straight to Uniswap router instead of through a function, and have no mechanism inside the Solidity contract to fix my mistake.

My one possible glimmer of hope, is being able to re-assign ownership of the contract.

Here's the piece of code that's preventing me from removing liquidity to re-add to a re-deployed contract:

```
function _transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
        if (!tradingOpen) {
            require (sender == owner ||  sender == address (this));
            return _basicTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        }
}
```

`tradingOpen` is currently `false`, and I am unable to change state of `tradingOpen`.  It is initially done in a create/add liquidity function, which requires native tokens being held by the contract.  I sent all the tokens into Uniswap when I manually created the LP.

I can reassign ownership of the contract, say to the router or to the pair, but when I'm analyzing other liquidity removal events, it looks like both the Uniswap router and the pair would have to be able to transfer tokens.
(example here: https://etherscan.io/tx-decoder?tx=0xb4e58740d8155c0ff928e748e90d9aec242cec4ad96afa753ff4ae1ae6a0208f)

Am I missing something?  Anyone that has more experience be able to help answer?  I haven't transferred ownership of the contract yet, hoping to do some more research before I try anything and completely bork it.

Thanks!